# Is there any difference between "how it is doable" and "how it can be done"?

Tags: grammar, phrases

I have a phrase which can be written in two ways:

> This page contains information about orders, like **how they are traceable** after production.

Or

> This page contains information about orders, like **how they can be traced** after production.

The first version even feels wrong to me. Is the second sentence better? Is there even a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Good example, incidentally.

Whether sth. is traceable and if so, how it *happens* to be, is obviously unrelated to how it can be traced. As such, there is no overlap of meaning, or any ambiguity.

By the way, this difference (a quality vs. a method) is very important in certain contexts.

In general, how something is doable (or otherwise) deals with the factors behind its being doable, while how sth. can be done, with the way to do it.

*meta:* at the moment I'm, sadly, unable to post comments fr

Comment: Can you expand on this difference? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I realize that I was thinking in the same direction but I couldn't order my thoughts and put them into words.